# Is there any way to merge questions?

Tags: support

There are two excellent questions about beginner RPGs; one specifically calls for younger players, but the answers are very similar between the two. Is there a way to flag these for merging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merging questions is possible, but it takes a moderator (diamond by name) to do it.
A moderator can choose two questions. The "copy question" will get wiped and locked, and all of its answers and comments will be transferred over to the "original" question.
[image]
[image]

The typical way to handle this is: vote to close one of the questions as a duplicate, then flag it for moderator attention with a short message.

Comment: Well I learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge questions but you can "close as duplicate".

First click on "close" (between "retag" and "flag") then select "Exact Duplicate"

[image: Close Question]

[image: Exact duplicate]

No one will be able to add answers, and a link will be displayed indicating this question is a duplicate.